# Distributing cost to user date range in DAX

Tags: business-intelligence, dax

In a retail environment, I have a cost associated with an Item/Offer that has a start and end date.  By dividing the cost by the total number of days, I can get the per day cost of each product in each offer.  How can I get the total cost of each item over a user entered date range?  Keep in mind that this date range can span multiple offers and multiple offers may overlap for any given day.

For example, I have Item ABC.  I have offers July 2016 and August 2016, which span the first to last day of each month.  July 2016 has a per day cost of $100 for Item ABC and August 2016 has a per day cost of $50 for Item ABC.  If the user wants to get the total offer cost for July 25th 2016 through August 10th , 2016 for Item ABC (7*$100 + 10*$50), what dax calculation should I use to get the total cost of $1,200 for the time period?

Comment: What is the structure of your model? Maybe there is a solution for this requeriment but it is hard to guess an expression that match your model.

Comment: I have a order shipment fact table that contains the shipped date of the order line.  This is the date that would match to the span of offer dates.  Then I have an offer dimension table that contains the start and end date of each offer and the per day cost.  It is linked to the fact table through a Offer key in a many to one relationship.

Comment: Add some sample data